# Indexing dynamic url

Tags: forms, get, seo, sitemap

I'm trying to index urls from a GET form.

I created permanent links as I have seen on other sites but google still not admit the url.

Error reading XML: malformed
Location: http://micompi.com/sitemapCiudades.xml
Number of line 8, column 82:
http://micompi.com/directorio-veterinario/ver/?provincia=Alava&poblacion=Todas&aseguradora=Todas/

¿What is the problem?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It was very easy!!!

Only need change & to `&amp;`